# rewrite css after div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this:

```
<dl id='1'></dl> <p>text from database</p>
```

i would like this after the div id 1:

```
<dl id='1'></dl> <p style='float:left';>text from database</p>
```

is that possible to rewrite the css in javascript or jquery?

regards

Frank

Answer (score 2):

Use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get `<p>` element and [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set the style:

```
$("#1").next("p").css("float", "left");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$("#first").next().css('float','left')
```